# flex/air mobile screenWidth 320px?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, mobile, width, resolution

How can I get the correct width of a component? For Example, I put a Spark Image Component `x:0; y:0; w:100%; height:100%;` in my view.

The debugger shows `image.width` to be 320px .... But my Phone has a width of 480px ... All simulator preset devices with its different resolutions gets 320px at 100% `image.width`...  same as other components.

Is this a bug? Why is the application thinking that every device has the same screen dimension?

I know there is the right `screenSize` on Capabilities.

Comment: I haven't had any problems with this. Which phone? Which version of flex?

Comment: What is the component's height?

Comment: Newes Flex Version from FlashBuilder 4.6 ... Samsung Galaxy S1 & S2

Comment: height is 463 (480-ActionBar?!)

Comment: The Application was forced to 160 dpi :-( ... thx for helping :-)